# How to implement template inner class function (C++)

Tags: c++, class, templates

considering the example below:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector {
    T* data;
public:
    class Iterator {
        T* i;
    public:
        Iterator& operator++();
    };
};
```

if I want to implement the 'operator++' function, it makes sence I'ld write like this:

```
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Iterator& Vector<T>::Iterator::operator++() {
    i++;
    return *this;
}
```

but then I'm getting those error lines:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'
error C2065: 'T' : undeclared identifier
error C2923: 'Vector' : 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'
```

Why does it happen? and what should I do to solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `template <typename T> typename Vector<T>::Iterator& Vector<T>::Iterator::operator++() {`

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't know that the member `Iterator` of `Vector` is necessarily a type, so you need to tell it with the `typename` keyword:

```
template <typename T>
typename Vector<T>::Iterator& Vector<T>::Iterator::operator++() {
//here^
    i++;
    return *this;
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more details about `typename`.

Comment: Ahhaha, «the smart thought goes to heads in the same time»  I even linked the same question *(the answer, though)*. Okay, removing.

Comment: Thank you vey much!! I'll see it.

Comment: or `auto Vector<T>::Iterator::operator++() -> Iterator&` in C++11